# Two speed/efficiency questions: 'For x in list' vs 'for x in xrange(len(list))', string matching with re vs ==

Tags: python

Two questions about speed/efficiency/best practices in Python. Which of the following are 'better' (faster, less memory-intensive, etc.):

1. ```
   for x in list:
       #do something to x
   ```

   or

   ```
   for x in xrange(len(list)):
       #do something to list[x]
   ```
2. ```
   for string in list_of_strings:
       for string2 in other_string_list:
           if string == string2:
               #do something
   ```

   or

   ```
   import re
   for string in list_of_strings:
       if re.match('%s'%(string),other_strings): #or re.search(etc)
            #do something
   ```

Not terribly pressing, I'm mostly just curious. I guess I could get some kind of raw data using timeit() or whatever, but I'd appreciate more depth than just "this one is faster than that one on your computer."

Comment: Why don't test it yourself, use the `timeit` module or for depth take a look at `dis` module.

Comment: This is two questions in one. Also, readability is far more important than speed in most cases. Never loop by index in Python, it's ugly as hell.

Comment: Always use `for x in list` (and don't name your variable `list`). It is much *cleaner* and usually faster, too, since python knows exactly what you intend to do.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Better yet, construct a set to test for membership in - as it'll be much faster than repeated checks for membership on a list.

Comment: Well that comment was for the first part of the question. But reading the second part again I just realize how rorrible it is. `O(n^2)` for a `x in y` check...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really compare these.

```
for x in mylist:
    # do something to x
```

is the usual idiom, but whatever you do to `x` won't affect `mylist` (unless `x` is mutable). If your goal is to modify `mylist` during the iteration, then

```
for x in xrange(len(list)):
    #do something to list[x]
```

is almost always bad form. A better way would be to use

```
for i, x in enumerate(mylist):
    # now you can work with x and/or change mylist[i] if you need to
```

But usually, you're even better off using a list comprehension or a generator expression:

```
newlist = [foo(item) for item in mylist if bar(item)]
```

All that depends on your use case.

As for your second question, using a regex for a plain string equality comparison is overkill. Nesting two for loops is horrible, too:

```
for string in one_list:
    if string in other_list:
        # do something
```

would be a little better, but I'm pretty sure that that can be improved if, again, more is known about your actual use case.

Comment: There isn't an 'actual use case', really. I've just fallen into the habit of using certain idioms and have been wondering about their value.